# Angular CLI component and directive CSS/SASS properties and variables

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I am working on an Angular 6 project and ran into a situation that I am not sure how to solve. I am writing a series of components and directives and using SCSS for my styles that contain variables to control the layout and theme.

What I am trying to accomplish is I would like to keep all the styling in the SCSS files but in some of my directives it makes much more sense to use a gutter setting instead of padding/margin so I am trying to structure my components to calculate their own margins and paddings. The problem is how can I define a "Gutter" css property (possibly similar to how they define ::ng-deep) or possibly a css variable to hold the value? Or another way to be able to define all the layout and theme variables in one file?

The only way I have thought of to accomplish this is to create a .json configuration file to hold the theme and other variables then export/import this into a SCSS variable file then use that as normal. Then I could import that same file into my Angular components and directives to use the variables. I am trying to stay away from things like using only the margin and setting that as the gutter, I would like to keep this clean and as readable as I can.

maybe something like:

### layout.json

```
{
   appGutter: 50px, 
   appFontSize: 1em,
   (…)
}
```

### layout.scss

```
@import 'layout.json'

// convert layout.json to SCSS variables 

app-root{
   font-size: $appFontSize;
}
```

### layout.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[pmnAppLayout]',
})
export class PmnAppLayoutDirective implements (…) {
   @HostBinding('style.margin') margin: string;

   (…)

   private _updateLayout() {
      /* Get value from json config file */
      var number = jsonCfg.appGutter;

    this.margin = `${gutter / 2}px`;
  }
}
```

Thats the basic idea, there is a lot more than just the gutter, this was the only way I could think of to simply convey my issue and possible solution. This seems to be allot of extra work, is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Question: can you explain in what situations this would be needed?

Comment: @Roy A situation would be just like the example above. Basically any time you have a variable/setting that is shared between SCSS and Angular.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a easy way to handle this, if a CSS variable is declared in say the body tag you can retrieve this variable value in Angular by using `getComputedStyle`. This way you do not have to create any .json config files. All that you need to do is to define your variables in an map so they can be exported into the body (or other tag) as a CSS variables then read those in Angular. Here is an example of how to accomplish this.

### _variables.scss

```
/*** Export SCSS variables to CSS ***/
@mixin PmnExportVariables($map, $prefix: null) {
  $mapPrefix: "--#{$prefix}";

  @if ($prefix){
    $mapPrefix: "#{$mapPrefix}-";
  }

  body {
    @each $name, $value in $map {
      #{$mapPrefix}#{$name}: $value;
    }
  }
}

$pmnLayout: ( 
   appGutter: 50px, 
   appFontSize: 1em,
);

@include PmnExportVariables($pmnLayout);

// To use the variable there are two options map-get and var()
app-root{
   font-size: map-get($pmnLayout, '--appFontSize');
   // font-size: var(--appFontSize);
}
```

### layout.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[pmnAppLayout]',
})
export class PmnAppLayoutDirective implements (…) {
   @HostBinding('style.margin') margin: string;

   (…)

   private _updateLayout() {
      // Get values from the body and convert to style
      let bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);

      /* Get the value*/
      var tVal = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue("--appGutter");

      this.margin = `${tVal / 2}px`;
  }
}
```